# Loop through each entity of a domain class in a service

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a domain class called StatusReport.  I also have a service called StatusReportsService.

Grails documentation gives examples like:

```
Book.list().each{}
```

However I get an error when I use:

```
StatusReport.list().each{}
```

Which gives me the error

```
Message: No signature of method: static com.tr.StatusReport.list() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: is(java.lang.Object), wait(), find(), wait(long), print(java.io.PrintWriter), find(groovy.lang.Closure)
```

How can I loop through each domain entity in a service?

Comment: Is your StatusReport class in the "domain" directory? It doesn't seem to be getting the GORM methods.

Comment: I have it in the domain directory, but in a subdirectory called statusReport where I have all the relational domain classes defined.  I fixed my problem using...

    import projectName.StatusReport.StatusReport